# How to check a character value at a position on a line and then add a character at another position on an another line using sed command

Tags: shell, sed

Eg. Input Text file

```
line 1 - Abchsffmskdv
line 2 - bsdvnld
line 3 - fsdgdhdh
```

If line 1, position 9 is s, then change line 3, position 4 to k

Output:

```
line 1 - Abchsffmskdv
line 2 - bsdvnld
line 3 - fsdkdhdh
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In the post editor, you can get pre-formatted blocks by inserting four blanks at the beginning of each line (there is to be an empty line before the block) - or just mark the block, and click "the `{}`-button. You can request line breaks appending two blanks to the line to be followed by a break.

Comment: You will get a much more friendly reception and much better help here if you show what code you have tried so far and describe what problems you were having with it. Without code, your question looks like a request for free consulting and many of the best experts here don't like that.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
sed '
/^.\{8\}s/ {        # if the 9th char == "s" then
    $!n             # flush current line and read next line (unless eof)
    $!n             # same as above to proceed to the line after next
    $!s/^\(.\{3\}\)./\1k/   # replace the 4th char with "k"
}' input.txt
```

or as a one-liner:

```
sed '/^.\{8\}s/{$!n; $!n; $!s/^\(.\{3\}\)./\1k/}' input.txt
```

input.txt looks like:

```
Abchsffmskdv
bsdvnld
fsdgdhdh
iiiiiiiisiii
iiiiiii
iiiiiiii
```

output:

```
Abchsffmskdv
bsdvnld
fsdkdhdh
iiiiiiiisiii
iiiiiii
iiikiiii
```

You'll see the script above replaces the 4th character of the next next
line if the pattern is found regardless of the line number.
If you want to fix the line number to  e.g. the 1st line, try instead:

```
sed '
1 {
    /^.\{8\}s/ {
        $!n
        $!n
        $!s/^\(.\{3\}\)./\1k/
    }
}' input.txt
```

output:

```
Abchsffmskdv
bsdvnld
fsdkdhdh
iiiiiiiisiii
iiiiiii
iiiiiiii
```

which modifies the 3rd line only.

Comment: I believe `n` called at the end of file will just end sed processing so perhaps               `sed -E '1{/^.{8}s/{n;n;s/./k/4}}' file` would be enough. However if the line to be changed was 203 this method might prove difficult to write.

Comment: @potong thank you for the suggestion. I'm afraid your code repeats the
last line in the output if the input file is shorter than three lines,
although it may be a rare case and out of assumptions.

Comment: I am using GNU sed and can not repeat your observations.

Comment: I see it may depends. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '1h;3{G;s/(...).(.*)\n.{8}s/\1k\2/}' file
```

Store the first line in the hold space and append it to line 3 and pattern match for the desired criteria.

An alternative:

```
sed -E '1h;3{x;/^.{8}s/{x;s/./k/4;x};x}' file
```